# jQuery Validation plugin work in two submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I validate my Form using [jQuery Validate Plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). Now i my form i have two input submit like this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/
javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>

<form id="formvalidetion">
    <input type="Submit" name="submit_gallery" value="submit">
    <input type="Submit" name="update_gallery" value="remove">
</form>
```

This plugin worked fine for two submit button.
I need to check and validate myfrom in submit value not in remove value.
My mean is if I click in submit check my form else validate not run.
How can I create this?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand of what you want is actually to reset the form, right?
Instead of this:

```
<input type="Submit" name="update_gallery" value="remove">
```

try this:

```
<input type="reset" name="update_gallery" value="remove">
```